# Fix for "You need to use a different package name" in Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm attempting to upload a build of an Android app to Google Play. I created a new keystore and signed it, but I get this error "You need to use a different package name" when I try to upload it.

I suspect that what happened is that another member of my team did this already but failed to commit their keystore file to version control. The app has never been published before, it is a new app.

I need a quick fix for this -- I won't be able to reach the team member who may have done this for several days. I tried removing the build that had been uploaded, but that didn't help.

Can I delete the entire app from Google Play and start over?

Can I change the package name? I've heard that this will work, but I'm not really sure what it entails. Do I have to actually change the package name of every class in my source code?

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the application in the following cases

**- Published apps or games that haven't been installed on any devices**

**- Published apps or games that no users are entitled to re-install**

from [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/publishing)

also google does not allow uploading an app with a different signature and the same package name. What you can do now is to change the entire package name and this can be done easily in Android studio

More details

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9023647

Comment: Thanks. I did change the package name, but to say it was "easy" is not at all true. I struggled with this for an hour, manually searching and replacing, broken builds, all kinds of stuff.

Comment: @Flarosa The easiest way to change the package name is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio